# How to get configuration element

Tags: c#, configuration, web-config, app-config

Helo

Can anybody explain me how to get configuration element from .config file. 
I know how to handle attributes but not elements. As example, I want to parse following:

```
<MySection enabled="true">

 <header><![CDATA[  <div> .... </div>  ]]></header>

 <title> .... </title>

</MySection>
```

My c# code looks like this so far:

```
 public class MyConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
    { 
        [ConfigurationProperty("enabled", DefaultValue = "true")]
        public bool Enabled
        {
            get { return this["enabled"].ToString().ToLower() == "true" ? true : false;   }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("header")]
        public string header
        {
                ???
        }
  }
```

It works with attributes, how do I do with elements (header property in above code) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found one way to do it.

There is IConfigurationSectionHandler interface that allows for things I want. It requires the one to write the method

```
 public object Create(object parent, object configContext, XmlNode section)
```

After it, u parse *section* on your own so I was able to fetch XmlElement's without a problem:

```
        header  = s["header"]  != null ? s["header"].InnerText   : String.Empty;
        title   = s["title"]   != null ? s["title"].InnerText    : String.Empty;
```

The down side of this is that interface is outdated but MSDN states that it will not be removed from future versions of the frameworks as it is used internally.

Comment: You didn't specify which version of .Net fw you target. For all versions above .Net 1.1 an [important remark](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.iconfigurationsectionhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) should be said: IConfigurationSectionHandler is deprecated in .NET Framework 2.0 and above.

Answer (score 6):

There is another approach for doing the same thing.

We could create an element by overriding `DeserializeElement` method to get string value:

```
public class EmailTextElement : ConfigurationElement {

    public string Value { get; private set; }

    protected override void DeserializeElement(XmlReader reader, bool s) {
        Value = reader.ReadElementContentAs(typeof(string), null) as string;
    }

}
```

Comment: It could better to use `reader.ReadElementContentAsString()` API.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pretty good custom config section designer tool you can use (and it's free):

[Configuration Section Designer](http://www.codeplex.com/csd)

EDIT:

I was looking into MSDN and it seems that custom config sections can't do what you want, ie. getting the config value from an element. Custom config elements can contain other config elements, but the config values always come from attributes.

Maybe you can put your html snippets into other files and refer to them from the config, like this.

```
<MySection enabled="true"> 
  <header filename="myheader.txt" />
  <title filename="mytitle.txt" />
</MySection>
```

Comment: Ugly solution for me. Would you like to set up html page title and header that way ? :) I wouldn't, especially cuz its going to be only 1 or few (html) lines. This eliminates attributs from the scenario as user can't use CDATA with them to be able to set html string.

Comment: Well, then you have to use a custom config file with custom parsing.

Comment: Vizu, 1 vote for the Configuration Section Designer link.  Saved me a lot of boring coding there.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Inherit the ConfigurationElement class and override its deserialize method.  Use the new class to represent elements with text content.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/ConfigurationTextElement.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Working with your example, you are going to override the Deserialization of  "header" in the ConfigurationElement to get the CDATA value.

```html
<MySection enabled="true">

  <header name="foo"><![CDATA[  <div> .... </div>  ]]></header>

  <title> .... </title>

</MySection>
```

```js
    public sealed class HeaderSection: ConfigurationElement {
      private string __Name, __CDATA;

      [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
      public string Name {
        get {
          return this.__Name;
        }
        set {
          this.__Name = value;
        }
      }

      [ConfigurationProperty("value", IsRequired = true)]
      public string Value {
        get {
          return this.__CDATA;
        }
        set {
          this.__CDATA = value;
        }
      }

      protected override void DeserializeElement(System.Xml.XmlReader reader, bool s) {
        this.Name = reader.GetAttribute("name").Trim();
        string cdata = reader.ReadElementContentAs(typeof(string), null) as string;
        this.Value = cdata.Trim();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ConfigurationManager.GetSection("SectionName")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx) method for getting the configuration section in the config files.

Comment: It's wrong. The question is about hot to design a custom config sections.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that inherits from System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement that represents an element in your configuration section.

There's a simple example in [the MSDN documentation for ConfigurationElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelement.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyx77cz3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), in **.NET 4** there's a new `CurrentConfiguration` property which gives you a reference to the top-level `Configuration` instance that represents the configuration hierarchy that the current `ConfigurationElement` instance belongs to.