# App.config format and accessing data in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, app-config

I'm new with editing app.config. I'd like to have this section in app.config:

```
<name1>
    <name2>
        <name3 att="something1">value1</name3>
        <name3 att="something2">value2</name3>
        ...
    </name2>
</name1>
```

How to create it and access it from code? I want to get `something1`, `something2`, `value1` and `value2`.
I found  [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173468/Four-Ways-to-Read-Configuration-Setting-in-Csharp), but it shows only how to get `something1`, not `something2`, `value1` and `value2` (Approach Four in tutorial).

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. First I needed to edit `ConfigurationElement` class for `<name3>`, I used the sample in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33109286/7871876). Then I needed to create class from [ConfigurationElementCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection?view=netframework-4.7) - so simpy coppied code for `UrlsCollection` class from the link and overwrited there all `UrlConfigElement` to my `ConfigurationElement` class.

```
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("name1") as Name1ConfigurationElement;
var collection = section.Name2;
foreach (SqlElement element in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a custom configuration collection by subclassing [`ConfigurationElementCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection?view=netframework-4.7).

Assuming `<name1>` is a immediate child of the root element you'll need:

- A custom section for `<name1>`
- It will need a custom collection for `<name2>`
- A custom element (to be a member of the collection) for each `<name3>`.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me. I posted coplete answer how I solved it to my post.